# How to change font style of list item not just the label

Tags: fonts, enumitem

I am trying to chnage the font style (to bold) for the item itself and not just the label

Below are the lines that I am using:

```
\setlist[enumerate]{font=\bfseries, wide=\parindent, noitemsep, topsep=0pt}
\setlist[itemize]{font=\bfseries, wide=\parindent, noitemsep, topsep=0pt}
```

however these lines change the label only and not the item itself.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add the option `before=\bfseries` in your `\setlist`s.

(This requires loading the package `enumitem`, which you evidently did already.)

---

If you want this option to only apply to a certain level, you can specify this in the `\setlist`. You can reset the font for deeper levels the same way. For example

```
\setlist[itemize, 1]{before=\bfseries}
\setlist[itemize, 2]{before=\normalfont}
```

would make only the first level of `itemize` lists bold.

Comment: That worked thank you, however I have a nested list and I wanted just level 1 to bf while level 2 shoud not be bolded. Can I control the level of the item to be bolded.

Comment: You can. See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Is the instruction `\setlist[itemize, 2]{before=\normalfont}` needed?

Comment: @Mico, yes. Since the second level of a list resides _inside_ the first one, all the formatting of the first level applies to the second one as well; we have to overrule it.

Answer (score 6):

You could load the `etoolbox` package and execute

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\bfseries}
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\bfseries}
```

in the preamble. This method works whether or not the `enumitem`-related code is present as well.