# How do I set the font size and spacing of list items globally using the enumitem package in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, spacing, enumerate, enumitem

Using the `enumerate` environment and the `\enumitem` package in LaTeX, I tried to create a list where the text of the individual items has a smaller font and is single-spaced. I would like to do this globally using the `\setlist` macro. The list should look like this, with the labels being arabic numerals in brackets:

(1) This is a first sentence.

(2) This is a second sentence.

(3) This is a third sentence.

This is the code I tried to far:

```
\documentclass[parskip = half, english, 12pt, twoside=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={(\arabic*)}}

\setlist[enumerate]{labelindent=2em}

\setlist[enumerate]{before=\small\sffamily\singlespacing}

\setlist[enumerate]{topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt}

\setlist[enumerate]{itemindent=2em}

\begin{document}

Some running text before the list:

\begin{enumerate}

\item This is the first sentence.

\item This is the second sentence.

\item This is the third sentence.

\end{enumerate}

Some running text following the list.

\end{document}
```

However, the line

```
\setlist[enumerate]{before=\small\sffamily\singlespacing}
```

changes neither the spacing nor the font of the list items. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You use a bit strange way to set `enumerate` features. You should use just one `\setlist` and there collected all desired settings. For example:

```
\documentclass[parskip = half, english, 12pt, twoside=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{nosep, 
                      label=(\arabic*),
                      labelindent=2em,
                      before=\small\sffamily}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
Some running text before the list. \lipsum[1][1-2]:
    \begin{enumerate}
\item   This is the first sentence.
\item   This is the second sentence.
\item   This is the third sentence.
    \end{enumerate}
Some running text following the list. \lipsum[1][3-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you after?

Comment: Thx, this did indeed do the job for me! Collecting all settings in one single \setlist command was the solution. Just one question for clarification: What does the comma after \sffamily in \setlist[enumerate,1]{nosep, label=(\arabic*), labelindent=2em, before=\small, \sffamily,} do?

Comment: @Chris, nothing. I forget to delete it when I test more options for your list. It not harm, but better is to delete it. Now MWE is corrected.

Comment: Great, thanks. Just another little issue: How do I set the text of all list items globally to single space? I tried adding \singlespacing in the \setlist macro, so that it looks like this: \setlist[enumerate,1]{nosep, label=(\arabic*), labelindent=2em, before=\small\sffamily\singlespacing}. However, this leads to some weird behaviour, with the paragraph immediately following the \enumerate environment being single-spaced too. Any suggestions on how to fix that problem?

Comment: @Chris, I dont understand what you after. My MWE has single spaced text. To clarify, what is your new problem, I suggest you to ask new question where provide MWE which reproduce your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I found the source of the problem: If I use the 'first' instead of the 'before' parameter, the changes affect only the list items and not the paragraph preceding it, i.e. the paragraph before the \enumerate environment is no longer single-spaced. The problem is also pointed out here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507362/enumitem-list-font-and-size. So everything works fine now.